# Remove everything from file names except for a particular part taken by RegEx

Tags: regex, bash

I have set of files, their names may contain alphabet, digits, spaces, dots, hyphens or underscores.

Possibilities can be:

```
word-123_AnotherWord-asdf1234567.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-ASDF1234567.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-1234567asdf.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-1a2s3d4f5g6.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-asdf-123456.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-asdf_123456.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-123456-asdf.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-123456_asdf.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-asdf123456-.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-asdf123456_.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord--asdf123456.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-_asdf123456.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord--asdf_12345.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-_asdf-12345.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-asdf--12345.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-asdf_-12345.mp4
... etc
```

I want:

(1) with RegEx **take last 11** text string of their names (whatever it was).

maybe RegEx for that can be like this:

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11})+(?:\.mp4)$/
```

(2) **rename** files with this taken RegEx part, to be:

```
outputregex.mp4
```

Something like this:

```
for i in *.mp4;
    do new_name=RegEx from i;
    $i rename to $new_name; 
done
```

Thanks for your cooperation!

Comment: I use Perl for renaming. Something along this line: http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/09/renaming-with-larry-wall/

Comment: Use [rename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html)

Comment: You say "hyphens included" but you remove it in your example. This is unclear.

Comment: sorry again @DenysSéguret , edited again,  is it clear now?

Comment: @SomeOne I hope it's clear. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example and comments, you seem to want this:

```
rename 's/^.*\W(\w{1,11}\.mp4)$/$1/' *.mp4
```

This first command only matches if there's a non alpha char before the word. If it's not a requirement, then you may use this one:

```
rename 's/.*?(\w{1,11}\.mp4)$/$1/' *.mp4
```

If you want the last 11 characters before the .mp4, whatever they are, use

```
rename 's/.*?(.{1,11}\.mp4)$/$1/' *.mp4
```

There's no need to loop, `rename` does it for you.

Comment: Thanks @Denys , but still want to limit the string length to 11, as you seen in my try

Comment: @SomeOne I found your precise requirement unclear. I edited. With rename it's easy to refine the regex replacement pattern for your specific use case.

Comment: yes, you're right, I wasn't clear, sorry about that. well, I've edited it now

Comment: I want to take the string from the end, last 11 before '.mp4'

Comment: I edited for what I understand of your requirement: take the biggest string of at most 11 chars before the .mp4 and starting after a non alpha.

Comment: Perfect! many thanks! @Denys :) , sorry for get you tired with me! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `rename` script:

```
for f in *.mp4; do
    rename 's/^.+?\b(\w+)(?=\.mp4$)/$1/' "$f"
done
```

---

You can just use (thanks to @anishsane) single command:

```
rename -n 's/^.+?([\w-]{11})\.mp4$/$1/' *.mp4
```

**PS:** Use `-n` option for **dry-run** of `rename` command.

Comment: `rename` can take multiple filenames at the same time. No need for the for loop.

Comment: sorry @anubhava , I wasn't clear enough, I want to take the string from the end, last 11 before '.mp4' ,  thank you!

Comment: I've edited my question again, included examples. thanks @anubhava

Comment: `rename -n 's/^.+?([\w-]{11})\.mp4$/$1/' *.mp4` would work even with edited question.