# Trimming filenames in bash with built-in tools only (no rename command)

Tags: bash

I have filenames of the form

```
word-123_AnotherWord--asdf_12345.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-_asdf-12345.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-asdf--12345.mp4
word-123_AnotherWord-asdf_-12345.mp4
```

...which I wish to trim to only contain the last 11 characters and extension.

---

My current attempt to do so looks like the following:

```
$ for i in *.mp4 ; do 
      mv "$i" "${/.*?(.{1,11}\.mp4)$/}";
done
```

But I gives me this error:

> bash: ${/.*?(.{1,11}.mp4)$/}: bad substitution

Any idea why?

This question is a continue to this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589973/remove-everything-from-file-names-except-for-a-particular-part-taken-by-regex) , but answer there works on my PC locally only, I didn't work on my server remotely!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you actually want that code to do?

Comment: ...that is to say: It's obvious to someone who knows bash why it fails. It's not obvious how it would be changed to work, because your intent in writing it isn't clear.

Comment: But change the names how? Give an example of an input name and an output name.

Comment: yes, it's a continue to this: [stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589973/remove-everything-from-file-names-except-for-a-particular-part-taken-by-regex) , but answer there works on my PC locally only, I didn't work on my server remotely!

Comment: Information from prior related questions should be included in new questions, when necessary for an answer. Also, you should include a link *in the question*, not just in comments.

Comment: thanks @CharlesDuffy for clarifying my question! don't know why some users down vote instead of asking to clarify what is not clear?! -_-

Comment: ok, thank you, I'm still new here, so please excuse me. will edit my question to include it.

Comment: Because people should follow the rules in the Help Center the first time they ask a question? Anyhow -- personally, I do both; downvote _and_ ask follow-up questions; edit if possible when those questions are answered; and reverse my downvote (as I've already done here) or even upvote if the question is good enough after editing (either mine or someone else's).

Comment: BTW, on your other question, @cuonglm had an answer that didn't require `rename`. It wasn't quite on-point due to a misunderstanding of the question, but if there had been a comment explaining how/why it was wrong (as there now is), I suspect it would have been corrected there earlier.

Comment: ok, thanks @CharlesDuffy, and please try to give us chance to learn with you here, and take in consideration that many people here not native  English speakers, which sometimes make expressing their thoughts not clear enough. anyway, thanks for editing my question, it looks more clear now, thank you.

Comment: It's generally rather clear when issues are caused by language barriers as opposed to lack of intent; content being present in only an obscured or difficult-to-follow way is observably different from that content not being present at all. In any event, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: yes, you are right, after reviewing revisions of question edits, found that I didn't provided details enough to clarify it, I apology for that!

Answer (score 2):

In the syntax `${var/pattern/replacement}`, there are several things wrong with the usage `"${/.*?(.{1,11}\.mp4)$/}"`:

- First, `var` isn't optional, it's mandatory.
- Second, `pattern` needs to be given in glob format, not regex format. If you want fancier expressions, use [extglob syntax](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob).
- Third, unless intent is to delete the parts matching the expression, the final `/` should actually contain something.

If you want to trim everything but the last 15 characters of each name (11 + 4 for the extension), that's trivial:

```
for i in *.mp4; do
  mv "$i" "${i:${#i}-15}"
done
```

---

Now, if you really want to use a regex:

```
name_re='.{1,11}\.mp4$'
for i in *.mp4; do
  [[ $i =~ $name_re ]] && mv -- "$i" "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
done
```

Comment: > the final `/` should actually contain something.

would you please clarify this point? an example like my case?

Comment: @SomeOne, because what you want to do isn't actually a substitution, `${var/pattern/replacement}` isn't the right value at all. However, `${var/pattern/}` is simply DELETING the pattern whenever it occurs, because it replaces it with nothing, not ISOLATING the pattern. Thus, if you updated your regex to be a valid shell pattern, even then this code would do the wrong thing, because it would be deleting what it matched and renaming the file to what was left after that deletion, rather than renaming the file to the match.